# Weglot link hooks not working (on sticky header)

Tags: javascript

I am using Weglot ([weglot.com](https://www.weglot.com)) for translation on my site ([aigle.ca](https://aigle.ca)).  I'm using link hooks since their widget was not working properly.

https://developers.weglot.com/technologies/javascript#link-hooks

Which is fine, however when you scroll down on the page, our menu becomes sticky, and the links no longer work, they just anchor to the top of the page (due to it being a hash). I've also noticed that the "active" language does not show properly on scroll.

I've tried using e.preventDefault(); to stop this behavior, but that didn't work.  I can't figure out why a sticky header would stop the plugin from working.

Does anyone know what would be causing it, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your sticky header is built dynamically so it destroys event listener on the Weglot button.

Can you replace in the link `#Weglot-xx` by `javascript:Weglot.switchTo('xx')`

For the style, you can also use a rule like

`html.fr a.top_link[data-dropdown-rel='fr'] { text-decoration: underline }`

Best